# Cognito does not call Lambda function in CustomSMSSender

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I received a request from my business team, they want to send custom sms and email verification code when new users register their new account. I followed the Cognito Lambda Custom SMS Sender Trigger from this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-sms-sender.html).
After looking at the lambda cloud watch log, I realized that my Cognito user pool does not trigger my lambda function. To allow you to help me debug better, below steps are what I did.

I created a lambda function and added permissions to it with this command:

```
aws lambda add-allow - function-name lambda_arn --statement-id "CognitoLambdaInvokeAccess" --action lambda: InvokeFunction --principal cognito-idp.amazonaws.com
```

Next, I created a CMK to decrypt the authorization key that Amazon Cognito generates.
then I created layer to allow my lambda function can import aws_encryption_sdk, CommitmentPolicy library.
then I updated user pool by the following command:

```
aws cognito-idp update-user-pool --user-pool-id my_user_poo_id --lambda-config "CustomEmailSender={LambdaVersion=V1_0, LambdaArn=arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:myaccountnumber:function:custom_email_lambda_trigger} , KMSKeyID = arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:myaccountnumber:key/3dfd9684-26f0-4543-928d-2618b964ad2b"
```

In the end I created a new user account, see whether the coginito triggers lambda but nothing happened.

Could someone please clarify how to add 3rd Cognito User pool as a verification method? Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: is there any way to do the lamda config connecting with userpool via console? pls help

Comment: The Custom Sender trigger would not get called if you are using a custom authentication flow (should be username and password to work as expected)

Comment: You can improve your question by stating which trigger you expected (I can guess it was `CustomSMSSender_SignUp`) and then also give us details on how you created the account.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem for CustomEmailSender. The solution for me was making sure that email is set as an attribute that requires verification.

1. Open the user pool in the AWS Console
2. Go to MFA and verifications
3. In 'Which attributes do you want to verify?' select the attributes you want to verify. It should not be 'No verification'.

If that doesn't help, check if you've added the triggers to the user pool correctly.
aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool --user-pool-id [user_pool_id]

Comment: is there any way to do the lamda config connecting with userpool via console? pls help

Comment: for new design console
1. Sign-up experience
2. Attribute verification and user account confirmation
3. Allow Cognito to automatically send messages to verify and confirm - Recommended

Comment: @HimanshuPatil I have that activated, but that Lambda is not still calling! I wonder what else should I do

Comment: @MohammadKermani I have written steps I have followed [here](https://himanshupatil.dev/custom-email-config-for-aws-cognito) do check it.

Comment: Something I realized is that the Custom Sender won't trigger in case you're using the Custom Flow. I don't know if this is documented somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

If you have done the mentioned steps, still not able to trigger the lambda, please follow the below steps.

1. Go to Cognito console and open your user pool "ap-south-1_W1nOJfGli"
2. Click on "Sign-up experience" tab.
3. Click on "Edit" button for "Attribute verification and user account confirmation"
4. Select the checkbox for "Allow Cognito to automatically send messages to verify and confirm - Recommended"
5. Select "Send SMS message, verify phone number" or "Send SMS message if phone number is available, otherwise send email message" as per your need
6. Save changes

Try now aws cognito-idp sign-up, should work.